# Laravel Sanctum - General understanding of tokens and refreshing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I used to use laravel passport for authentication. That was a little bit overkill, since I used it only for a seperated vue frontend and a backend on the same domain. So that's why I'm trying laravel sanctum right now.

The authentication with sanctum works fine. After the authentication, I save the token to the users localStorage. Now my problem: I want to logout the user, once he stopped using my api for 24 minutes.

But the token lasts forever. So I added `'expiration' => 24,` to the sanctum config. But know the token is getting expired, no matter how many times I use it during that 24 minutes.

Now I'm asking myself, how is the api intended to be used?

1. Should I always return a new plain text cookie on every request and replace it with the old one in the localStorage and delete all the tokens from the database, once the user is requesting the logout?
2. Should I change the `'expiration' => 24,` to null and check the token table of my database with every request, if the current datetime + 24 minutes is more than the current token.last_used_at column?

Or am I missing something?

Thanks!